# How do I use /testfor to detect a kill with the objectives?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So in my new server I just added a PvP area, and I ran into a problem: I can't figure out how to give a player money for killing someone.

**Here's my current set up:** What I have is an objective that detects player kills with a command block on a Redstone clock.

The clock has the following code inside: `/testfor @a[score_killreward_min=1]`. Afterwards (this is the command I need) **I need another command which is supposed to pay that player for killing someone.** Lastly, I just have a command that sets the score back to 0. `/scoreboard players set @a killreward 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution. I needed a command block in the middle with the following command:

```
/eco give @a[score_killreward_min=1]
```

I put a delay for the redstone current afterwards to set it to 0.

Comment: can you please award yourself "best answer"? this way, people don't come to try and answer it, and Community can stop bumping this.